# Spring Integration xslt-transformer doesn't work with namespace

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I use Spring Integration:

```
<int-xml:xslt-transformer input-channel="partnerTransformation" 
output-channel="serviceChannel" 
xsl-resource="classpath:/META-INF/vendorTransformerXml.xsl"/>
```

The input XML message:

```
<ns1:persons  xmlns:ns1="http://com.test.xslt/test"  xmlns:ns3="http://universal.consumerrequest.schema.model.tci.ca">
<ns3:person>
    <ns3:name>John</ns3:name>
    <ns3:family>Smith</ns3:family>
</ns3:person>
<ns3:person>
    <ns3:name>Raza</ns3:name>
    <ns3:family>Abbas</ns3:family>
</ns3:person>
```

and the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://com.test.xslt/test" xmlns:ns3="http://universal.consumerrequest.schema.model.tci.ca">


<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="ns1:persons/ns3:person">


<xsl:value-of select="ns3:family"/>
<xsl:value-of select="ns3:name"/>
</xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it doesn't work, but it works well without namesapce, appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way Java XML parsers handle namespaces by default. There's a few things you can do:

- Convert the input XML to a String before feeding it to the XSLT transformer. This works fine in my testing
- If you are building the document yourself, e.g.

  ```
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
  Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(...);
  ```
- If you don't have to worry about namespaces, probably the easiest thing is to change your XSLT:

  ```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
       xmlns:ns1="http://com.test.xslt/test"
   xmlns:ns3="http://universal.consumerrequest.schema.model.tci.ca">


   <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='person']">
         <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='family']" />
         <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='name']" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```